# AWS IAM add user to group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have already created a user("testuser1") and i want to assign that user to a existing group("users").

```
AddUserToGroupRequest add = new AddUserToGroupRequest("users", "testuser1");
AmazonIdentityManagement aim =new AmazonIdentityManagement();
aim.addUserToGroup(add);
```

This is the code i am using but since AmazonIdentityManagement() is an interface i cant call its methods, so can you suggest any another way.

Sorry if I am doing something wrong, please correct me.

Thank You
-Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AmazonIdentityManagement` is an `interface`. You need to create an object of a class that implements it.

For example, this:

```
AmazonIdentityManagement aim = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient()
```